# Ubuntu 21.10 and Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 - No Internet

Tags: drivers, internet, intel

I've been troubleshooting a wifi issue for days now and I wanted to see if there are any suggestions from the community.

I have a newer Thinkpad X1 with Xubuntu 21.10 installed. Everything has been working as expected then earlier this week I was no longer able to connect to the internet. I am still able to connect to other servers/machines within my network just fine. I've also tested 3 different networks: 1 wireless (starlink router), 1 wireless (LTE hotspot), 1 ethernet/usb dongle (DSL router) and none of them can connect outside, so I believe the issue is most likely related to the laptop, not the routers.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Here are some more details that I thought would be useful:

Edit: full output of wireless-info script can be found here: https://pastebin.com/n5ag3jXg
(source:[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180))

1. uname -a

`Linux <***> 5.13.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 19 08:59:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

2. hostnamectl

```
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: <***>
         Boot ID: <***>
Operating System: Ubuntu 21.10                    
          Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-21-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9
```

3. lshw -C network

```
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: <***>
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-21-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.u ip=192.168.1.167 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:603d1cc000-603d1cffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: ipv6leakintrf0
       serial: <***>
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=5.13.0-21-generic
```

4. ifconfig

```
cooper@agentcooper:~$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether <***>  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ipv6leakintrf0: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet6 <***>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 <***>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether <***> txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21809  bytes 2213565 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 51738  bytes 3794209 (3.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51738  bytes 3794209 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether <***>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.167  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 <***>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <***>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1498  bytes 304462 (304.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 95  bytes 11303 (11.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

5. dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   72.796235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   72.796244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[   72.796472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   72.846939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[   73.035082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: <***>
[   73.050156] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

6. ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103952 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209628 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1223144 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1300764 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1329296 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1334856 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1052796 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053004 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1147104 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1163672 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1226208 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1248672 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1252748 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1106248 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103968 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209644 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1223160 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1300780 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1329312 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1334872 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1052816 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053020 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-50.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1147120 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-53.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1163688 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-55.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1226224 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-59.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1248688 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-62.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1252764 Oct 20 05:22 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-63.ucode
```

7. modinfo iwlwifi

```
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-mr-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf4-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-mr-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf4-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
srcversion:     5B7C9BA9AE71C6036ED89E0
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002727sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00007E40sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002729sv*sd*bc*sc*i*

...

depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.13.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        <***>
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      <***>
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

7. lspci

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b8 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 174a
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Device 1eac:1001
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find much to try from the comments on that thread. However, I did run the script and add the results to my question. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Which interface? `w1p0s20f3` is up and connected to `Skynet` (although its MTU should be 1492 not 1500). Downvoted due to "logvomit", the gratuitous posting of reams of unrequested, verbose noise that we have to wade through to understand your question. And you didn't mention `docker`. Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @waltinator Why did you say MTU should be 1492? Did I miss something?

Comment: I posted a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412633/ubuntu-22-and-intel-wi-fi-6-ax201-troubleshooting Apparently, still no definitive answer? Did you have any luck blur13 ?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this (April 2022) the AX201 card is working under Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS using the HWE kernel 5.13.0-40-lowlatency

Answer (score 0):

You might try disabling SecureBoot in your bios/uefi settings.  The drivers don't always play nice with SecureBoot.

The other thing you might try is to turn off powersaving:

`sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*`

and then

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`