# lenovo thinkpad x13 gen2 Mobile Broadband not working

Tags: mobile-broadband

I did install ubuntu, everything except the broadband connection dont work. The same sim card worked on windows. So generally the hardware and sim cant be the problem.

If I try to enable I get the message:

> GD.Bus.Error.org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.WrongState: Cannot register modem: not yet enabled

Modem:
Manufacturer: quectel
Model: em120r_gl

```
System:
  Host: benjamin-mini Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: LENOVO product: 20W80015MZ
    v: ThinkPad X13 Yoga Gen 2 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20W80015MZ v: SDK0J40697 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: N39ET61W (1.40 )
    date: 12/28/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 34.8 Wh (81.9%) condition: 42.5/52.9 Wh (80.3%)
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    cache: L2: 5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2392 min/max: 400/4700 cores: 1: 819 2: 2800 3: 2800
    4: 2800 5: 2800 6: 2800 7: 2800 8: 1522
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: IMC Networks Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-38-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: 88:d8:2e:60:c1:f1
  IF-ID-1: wwan0 state: down mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 88:D8:2E:60:C1:F5 bt-v: 3.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 11.47 GiB (2.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital
    model: PC SN730 SDBQNTY-512G-1001 size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 195.12 GiB used: 11.44 GiB (5.9%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 31.1 MiB (32.4%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 0
Info:
  Processes: 283 Uptime: 7m Memory: 15.35 GiB used: 2.68 GiB (17.4%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

Has anyone an idea what's the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to help you, we would need some more information about your Ubuntu. Which version did you install? Could you open a terminal and execute `inxi -F`. Copy the output and put it into your **question** (not the comments)

Comment: Here the inxi output, ubuntu is 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Ok, it won't help you, but you're not alone. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418000/906933).  You will find more information if you copy this string `Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201` in our searchbar above.

Comment: Hm maybe this https://mobile-broadband.pages.freedesktop.org/docs/modemmanager/fcc-unlock/

Comment: This is from your question. I did install ubuntu, everything except the broadband connection dont work. It is quite confusing I do not think this is what you wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is as nobody says the fcc lock. To get the modem running you have to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libmbim-utils
sudo apt-get install libqmi-utils
sudo ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/*
```

For more infos: https://mobile-broadband.pages.freedesktop.org/docs/modemmanager/fcc-unlock/

Comment: This also worked on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 9 with a Quectel Wireless Solutions Co., Ltd. EM120R-GL LTE Modem