# mobile broadband not connecting to network operator

Tags: internet, lenovo, broadband

it took me a while and lots of googling but I think I have my modem set up etc. It now looks as if the laptop keeps trying to connect but disconnect (the icon is flickering).
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Carbon X1 gen 9. Any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK I found the anwer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461671/lenovo-thinkpad-x13-gen2-mobile-broadband-not-working