# Poor WiFi Signal on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I recently have started dual booting my work laptop with Kubuntu 21.10 and Windows 11 and for some reason the WiFi signal when running Kubuntu is extremely poor and near unusable. I am experiencing around 0.2MBps compared to about 20MBps from my phone and when running Windows in the same room.

I have a `Dell Vostro 15 7510` laptop and my WiFi chip is the `Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi`.
I am running `Kubuntu 21.10` with `Kernal 5.13.0-46-generic`.

I have tried some suggestions I have found, such as changing my MTU settings to 1492 (it was at 1500 by default). I also disabled the power saving settings and secure boot. These solutions were outlined both [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380148/ubuntu-21-10-and-intel-wi-fi-6-ax201-no-internet) and [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206469).

I'm a bit stumped as to what I should try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would likely boot Ubuntu 22.04 LTS media & use the "*Try Ubuntu*" type option to use it in *live* mode and see if it works there..  [Ubuntu 21.10 EOL notices are already out](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) which includes flavors like Kubuntu, so you'll be moving to a newer kernel (thus newer kernel modules, aka *drivers*) very soon anyway; and thus I'd get there first before spending time on the issue  (*I'm assuming ethernet is available.. if your device doesn't have this my comment may be different..*)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will try out 22.04 and see if the issue persists with that OS. I do unfortunately want to keep my current install as I have it set up exactly how I want it, is there any way I can proceed with an update to the LTS version or an updated version of my current OS or do I just need to wait until Kubuntu pushes an update my way? Unfortunately ethernet is not really a viable option for me at work as we don't have any data points installed yet in my area (just fresh in a new office).

Comment: I suggest you read release announcements eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/ or the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS release notes as many links or a section on upgrading is provided (eg. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start for desktop from prior link, it was a different link for servers).  You can also *upgrade via re-install* and have your files untouched, and *manually installed* package re-installed (where from Ubuntu repositories) too (*my backup should I have issues with release-upgrade, or my goto if short on time*)

Comment: FYI:  I'd still run a *live* test, as the difference will primarily be related to the kernel stack, ie. on 21.10 you're using 5.13 where as 22.04 (*or 20.04.5 when that's reached*) can be easily tested using the *live* media without any install/change-to-your-system.. As it's possible to *test* without any changes it's why I'd do that first.. as if it solves the issue, it's an upgrade that's compulsory in days-weeks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the recommendation to upgrade to 22.04. I just ran the update and this managed to fix everything. Glad this worked out! Thanks again